# Allowing users to build a top ten list

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a database with tables and rows of player names, and links to pages of those players:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names, playerPics, Linkpages
FROM PlayerDB
WHERE Linkpages IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Names
```

This query gives me a list of name, with pictures and links

However, I'm having trouble writing a script that would let my site's users build their own top ten lists from all player names.

What I would like is to display ten dropdown menus, one for each position. Once a user has selected all ten player names, the user would see this on a separate page:

```
1.-Stam Smith
2.-Carl Logen
. 
.
.
10.-William Hess
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Hiya! Be careful; requests for tutorials are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow. Instead, describe the question and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: well that is sad why was my question edited?, and why is asking for a tutorial frowned upon? SO is for when people are stuck, and I AM stuck on how to start building that script, I have done many searched trying to find a tutorial on how to build a php form that also becomes a top ten

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources (whether libraries, tutorials or software) tend to attract spam and opinionated answers, which doesn't meet the Question/Definitive Answer model that Stack Overflow uses. [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203232/175498) a more specific meta topic about it. Basically, I edited your question to remove references to tutorials, which will help your question stay open on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names, playerPics, Linkpages FROM PlayerDB WHERE Linkpages IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Names LIMIT 10");
```